# Error while running npm install @material-ui/core in VSCode in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

PS C:\Users\misss\tnodejs_ec> npm install @material-ui/core

> > 

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tnodejs_ec@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\misss\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\misss\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-04T09_27_24_111Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\misss\tnodejs_ec>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to install material UI then use force to npm no matter what happen you have to install this forcefully.

```js
npm install @material-ui/core --force
```

Answer (score 0):

MUI doesn't work with React18, its because of an issue in previous release of MUI, now its been fixed in the latest version.

If you want to stick to `@material-ui/core@4.12.4` then your best bet is to include the `--legacy-peer-deps` option. I got it working after adding this option like

```
npm install @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps
```

However, the best way forward is to update to the latest [MUI version](https://mui.com/versions/#released-versions). Current version of MUI is [v5.10.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material)

PS: with recent updates the name of the package in NPM registry has been updated too

> old: `@material-ui/core`

> new: `@mui/material`

Don't forget to update your `package.json`